# Separating integer and fractional part of a decimal number

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I want to separate a numeric decimal number, storing the integer part in bash variable `ts` and the fractional part in variable `fr`.

Had a go with parameter expansion, but keep getting the original number.

```
t=13.491675 
ts=${t#![0-9]*}
fr=${t%*![0-9]}
```

Comment: why not split on the `.`? do you have other numbers that you need to split that are not delimited by `.`? do you have to address numbers with the a 1000's separator? do you need to support european numbers (ie, comma instead of period)? I'm surprised you're not getting an error (eg, `-bash: ![0: event not found`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with any [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Usage_worldwide):

```sh
shopt -s extglob
t=13.491675
ts="${t%%[^0-9]+([0-9])}"
fr="${t##+([0-9])[^0-9]}"
```

Comment: Why does the use of `extglob` need a point? What is the point of using anything at all? If this was a technical (rather than rhetorical) question, the answer is that `extglob` enables (for example) the `+(...)` construct. Bash uses globs in many ways, not only for matching file sytem paths. Globs are used also in string comparisons and in expansions such as these.

Comment: Very nice, upvoted. Even if, according your Wikipedia link, we are not 100% sure it works in Antarctic. More seriously, as we don't know if the decimal separator shall be retained in the fractional part, it could be interesting to add a solution that preserves it (`"${t##+([0-9])}"`).

Comment: Because it is not needed here. This can be achieved using ordinary globs as well, hence the downvote.

Comment: Please post a 100% equivalent example with ordinary globs then.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Oguz might have been thinking of these two: `${t%%[,.]*}` & `${t##*[,.]}`. In any case, don't take any of these personally, it's just us lawyers talking the intricacies of the Bash law :)

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan I was thinking of this: `ts=${t%[!0-9]*} fr=${t#"$ts"?}`. If it is certain that `t` is a proper decimal non-integer, this is enough. Otherwise none of the solutions proposed on this page is gonna work.

Comment: @oguzismail that's a nice solution, especially the use of a word expansion in the pattern position of the `#` expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Use plain POSIX expansion:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

t=13.491675

# Trim-out shortest trailing dot followed by any number of any character
ts=${t%.*}

# Cut shortest leading any number of any character followed by a dot
fr=${t#*.}

# Debug printout
printf 't=%s\nts=%d\nfr=%d\n' "$t" "$ts" "$fr"
```

Or use Bash's here-string to split with the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator set to the dot:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

t=13.491675

IFS=. read -r ts fr <<<"$t"

printf 't=%s\nts=%d\nfr=%d\n' "$t" "$ts" "$fr"
```

Or same with IFS split an unquoted variable as arguments

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

t=13.491675

# Save IFS
__OIFS="$IFS"

IFS=.
set -- $t
ts=$1
fr=$2

IFS=$__OIFS

printf 't=%s\nts=%d\nfr=%d\n' "$t" "$ts" "$fr"
```

Comment: Could you just `unset IFS` in order to revert it to its default value? Instead of using the temporary `__OIFS`.

Answer (score 0):

I share a solution that works. Example:

`enter code here`w=g/77
`enter code here`if (i<15) {scale=0; u=g/77; w=w-u; scale=5; }
`enter code here`if (i=1){v=w}
`enter code here`g=g*g
`enter code here`if (w=v){print v; }

Use the other comments to help, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Let's first treat numbers as numbers and use `bc` if it's available:

```
$ t=13.491675
$ read ts fr < <(printf 't=%s; print t/1," ",t-t/1\n' "$t" | bc)
$ echo "$ts + $fr = $t"
13 + .491675 = 13.491675
```

The same can be acomplished with the computing capabilities of `awk`:

```
$ read ts fr < <(echo "$t" | awk '{printf("%d %f\n", int($1), $1-int($1))}')
$ echo "$ts + $fr = $t"
13 + 0.491675 = 13.491675
```

> Note the extra leading `0` in the fractional part.

Or a mixture of `printf` to extract the integer part and `bc` to extract the fractional part:

```
$ t=13.491675
$ printf -v ts '%.0f\n' "$t"
$ fr=$(printf '%s-%d\n' "$t" "$i" | bc)
$ echo "$ts + $fr = $t"
13 + .491675 = 13.491675
```

Or, if `bc` is not an option, `printf` and bash parameter expansion to finish the job:

```
$ t=13.491675
$ printf -v ts '%.0f\n' "$t"
$ fr="${t#$i}"
$ echo "$ts + $fr = $t"
13 + .491675 = 13.491675
```

To get rid of the decimal separator, if needed, we can use one more parameter expansion:

```
$ fr="${fr:1}"
```

or:

```
$ fr="${fr:2}"
```

for the `awk`-based solution.